# Can anyone identify the year, make, model of this car?

Tags: vehicle-identification

This car struck mine in my work parking lot. I am trying to identify for insurance reasons, and need the information to narrow down my search. Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

[image: Passenger-side view]

[image: Corner view]

There is a chrome stripe below the dark one in the side view, running the length of the car.

Thank you again!

Sev

**EDIT: (by - Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 ♦)**

I've done a little photo mastery on these (cough/cough). Since the images are stretched on the horizontal axis, I've edited them to shrink them left/right a bit. I think they are a lot more recognizable, though I still cannot place the exact year/model of the car. Might help someone else, though:

[image]

[image]

I'll see if I can histogram the license plate later and post that as well with something which is recognizable.

Edit: This is in the United States, southern California.
Also: Thank you!

Comment: What country was this taken in?

Comment: Looks like a 90's Buick to me. Possibly a Park Avenue.

Comment: It is a Buick, no doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1994 Buick Regal is my guess. [See this page for similar looking vehicles](http://bestcarmag.com/makes/Buick/Regal/1994-Buick-Regal).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd say its a pre-1993 [Buick Regal sedan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buick_Regal#Third_generation_(1988%E2%80%931996)) (with pre facelift grille)